# Get number of times regex .replace() occurs

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm building an html linter, and first thing I am trying to do is remove all of the alt attributes. I'm using a regex to replace alt tags. Is there a way to get the number alt codes removed.

If you paste:

> alt="23432" one two three alt='12312' four five six alt = "1124412"

You should get one two three four five six, and I would like to store 3 into a variable called numReplaced.

```js
function removeAlts(input) {
 var textIn = document.getElementById("textIn").value;
 var regex = /alt\s*=\s*[\"\'][a-zA-z0-9\s]*[\"\']/ig;
 var textOut = textIn.replace(regex, '');
 document.getElementById("textIn").value = textOut;
  //var numReplaced = ????
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="removeAlts()">Remove Alts</button>
<div class="title">
 <h3>Paste code in box below and press button to remove alts!</h3>
</div>
<textarea name="input" id="textIn" cols="60" rows=15"></textarea>
```

Comment: You need to take into account cases like `alt="it's okay"`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a replacer function, and increment a counter every time it's called. You should also fix your regex to *capture* the initial double or single quote in the `alt` attribute, so that it can be matched later with a backreference. With this backreference strategy, you'll also be able to match `alt`s with quotes in them, so add `"'` to the character set.

In addition, you can use the `i` flag instead of repeating `[a-zA-Z`, and `\d` instead of `0-9`. Also, quotes do not need to be escaped in regular expression literals.

```js
function removeAlts(input) {
  var textIn = document.getElementById("textIn").value;
  var regex = /\s*alt\s*=\s*(["'])[a-z\d\s"']*?\1/ig;
  let counter = 0;
  var textOut = textIn.replace(regex, () => {
    counter++;
    return '';
  });
  document.getElementById("textIn").value = textOut;
  console.log(counter);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="removeAlts()">Remove Alts</button>
<div class="title">
  <h3>Paste code in box below and press button to remove alts!</h3>
</div>
<textarea name="input" id="textIn" cols="60" rows="15">
  <tag alt="foo"></tag>
  <tag alt="bar"></tag>
  <tag alt="that's okay"></tag>
</textarea>
```

But it would be far more elegant to use `DOMParser` to search for everything with an `alt` attribute, and remove them

```js
function removeAlts(input) {
  var textIn = document.getElementById("textIn").value;
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(textIn, 'text/html');
  const alts = doc.querySelectorAll('[alt]');
  console.log(alts.length);
  alts.forEach(elm => elm.removeAttribute('alt'));
  document.getElementById("textIn").value = doc.body.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="removeAlts()">Remove Alts</button>
<div class="title">
  <h3>Paste code in box below and press button to remove alts!</h3>
</div>
<textarea name="input" id="textIn" cols="60" rows="15">
  <tag alt="foo"></tag>
  <tag alt="bar"></tag>
  <tag alt="that's okay"></tag>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Your regex will not work properly in cases like `alt="that's okay"` since it contains double quotes and single quotes

Comment: Yep, need to fix OP's regex to capture that character and backreference it later

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about DOMParser :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use same quote in the end of your pattern like this:
`/alt\s*=\s*(["']).+\1/ig`